# How to change the order of items in the algebra view of geogebra?

Tags: geogebra

I'm using GeoGebra Classic 5 and have a bigger project where I've encountered the problem that I can't find any way to change the order of elements in the list of the algebra view after the elements are created. Sure I could of course just delete the affected elements and create them in the right order but I'm sure there must be a better solution to such a simple problem.

Here you see what it looks like right now, and how I would like it to look

[image: 1]

I've tried looking through the properties panel and all the navbar buttons but there seems to be no way to change the order of the list. The only thing I've found is the "sort by" setting that changes the order but doesn't let the user decide the order other than some predefined sortings. I also haven't been able to find anything about this on google or the geogebra documentation. Hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, Geogebra has no such ability. It can only use one of its predefined sortings. The default is "construction order," which Geogebra takes to be the order you define things in, unless an earlier-defined item is changed to depend on a later-defined one; then it has to come after it in construction order. You can sometimes use this principle as a hack to rearrange things, by making the earlier item depend effectlessly on the later one. In the case shown in the question, I tried redefining `r = 0.15 + 0*RightSide(eq1)`, which did change the order to the desired one, but had the undesirable side effect of turning `r` into a function of two variables. So I don't think that hack is really usable in this particular case. You can then change the definition of `r` back to what it was, and it will remain after `eq1` -- but is that really easier than deleting `r` and redefining it?

Another hack/workaround I sometimes use is put the objects into Layers so that ones I want to come later are in higher Layers, and then sort by Layer. That technique can provide the order you want, without changing the definitions of the entities, but it does have the side effect of showing the Layer headings.